# htaccess variables after .html not showing

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

if have the following rule
`RewriteRule ^userCP/([a-zA-Z]+).html /userCp.php?action=$1`
and what i need is to catch additional variables after the .html in the form of .html?var1=asas

i tried this 
`RewriteRule ^userCP/([a-zA-Z]+)(\.html) /userCp.php?action=$1&vars=$2` but of course all i'm getting for $2 is .html

The final outcome should look something like userCP/compose.html?id=1&return=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is add the `QSA` flag: [Flag QSA <sup>Apache Docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa).

```
RewriteRule ^userCP/([a-zA-Z]+).html /userCp.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
```